# Cross-Site-Scripting(XSS) Finding The Exact Payload For A Target

Tags: xss

I am learning XSS just started few weeks back so I am using the Burp Suite Free Academy Labs. I would love to be taught on how to craft the payload rather than been given the answer straight so to learn.

Can I please get advice also on lets say this was a real world situation without me being given hints on what actually is being sanitized how can I identify that `1.This characters are being sanitized`  and `2.After me trying all that I know like I did it did not mean that the web application is not vulnerable to XSS so how would I actually know that I am the right place that this web app is vulnerable I just need to fix my payload?`

Below is the problem set of the lab

```
This lab contains a reflected cross-site scripting vulnerability in the search functionality but uses 
a web application firewall (WAF) to protect against common XSS vectors.

To solve the lab, perform a cross-site scripting attack that bypasses the WAF and alerts 
document.cookie.

Note: Your solution must not require any user interaction. Manually triggering an alert in your own 
browser will not solve the lab.
```

So here was my thought process to solving this problem:

1. I knew that in my payload I should not have the alert()
2. So I tried event `handlers`, `meta tags`, `changing the characters making lower and uppercase to check whats actually being sanitized here.`
3. I then realized like all the payloads I know  are being sanitized because they either have `tags` or `alert.`
4. I then came to `encoding` and `ASCII` just to remember that also the payloads that I know they  have `alert` or `HTML TAGS`
5. I then finally after trying that which I know I resorted to going online and search for XSS payloads, just to find out that all those that I was finding they also have `Tags` or `alert` one way or another which are being sanitized by the lab.

`THEN AT THIS POINT THATS WHEN I REALIZED I HAVE REACHED A DEAD END`

Comment: what about eval, prompt, base64 or assigning a function to a variable?

Comment: The prompt for sure would not work, as it works in similar way as the alert and the Lab question stated the following:

`Note: Your solution must not require any user interaction. Manually triggering an alert in your own 
browser will not solve the lab.`

Comment: Prompt is alternate way to pop a message. Please read about it... Stackoverflow is not intended for doing your homework for you.